# S3FS IMCE File upload issue for old files in Upgraded site

Tags: files, 9

I have a question on IMCE File upload. Hope someone might have come across the similar issue.

Installed modules:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs
- https://www.drupal.org/project/imce

We have added a file/image field and chosen following option from **Manage form display** [admin/structure/types/manage/mycontent-type/form-display] to have Open **File Browser option** above the specific field.

**Allow users to select files from Imce File Manager for this field.**

Also, We have configured right way to populate specific S3 bucket files when we click on **File Browser option**. We could see all our S3 bucket files when
We have upgraded our Drupal 8.x site to the latest Drupal 9.2.4.

The only problem is that, we are able to upload new files but not able to select old files. When we select old files, it just loads field and nothing happens.

Unfortunately, we could see the only error when we try to upload a old file and looks like this is not the root cause.

```
#0 ROOT-FOLDER\core\includes\bootstrap.inc(312): _drupal_error_handler_real(2, 'strip_tags() ex...', 'D:\\Applications...', 103)
#1 [internal function]: _drupal_error_handler(2, 'strip_tags() ex...', 'D:\\Applications...', 103, Array)
#2 ROOT-FOLDER\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php(418) : eval()'d code(103): strip_tags(Array)
#3 ROOT-FOLDER\vendor\twig\twig\src\Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_2a6388b68ac7765833842f4b9b7c85edae837f9d5494558acc0881d920a11091->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#4 ROOT-FOLDER\vendor\twig\twig\src\Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#5 ROOT-FOLDER\vendor\twig\twig\src\Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#6 ROOT-FOLDER\core\themes\engines\twig\twig.engine(65): Twig\Template->render(Array)
#7 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager.php(384): twig_render_template('themes/custom/b...', Array)
#8 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php(436): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array)
#9 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php(201): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, true)
#10 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php(145): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, true)
#11 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php(578): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render\{closure}()
#12 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php(146): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#13 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer.php(66): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderRoot(Array)
#14 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer.php(76): Drupal\Core\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup), 'imce_page', Array)
#15 ROOT-FOLDER\modules\contrib\imce\src\ImceFM.php(689): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup), 'imce_page', Array)
#16 ROOT-FOLDER\modules\contrib\imce\src\ImceFM.php(708): Drupal\imce\ImceFM->buildRenderPage()
#17 ROOT-FOLDER\modules\contrib\imce\src\Imce.php(27): Drupal\imce\ImceFM->pageResponse()
#18 ROOT-FOLDER\modules\contrib\imce\src\Controller\ImceController.php(35): Drupal\imce\Imce::response(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy), 's3')
#19 [internal function]: Drupal\imce\Controller\ImceController->page('s3', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#20 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php(578): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#22 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#23 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array)
#24 ROOT-FOLDER\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php(158): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#25 ROOT-FOLDER\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php(80): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#26 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#27 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#28 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#29 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#30 ROOT-FOLDER\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#31 ROOT-FOLDER\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel.php(717): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#32 ROOT-FOLDER\index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#33 {main}
```

Could someone please help us in finding the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Hope someone might have come across a similar issue that I had faced. 

Kindly reply to me If anyone has a solution for it.

Appreciate your help in advance.